# checked in datagridview to listbox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, listbox

I have a checked gridview and listbox, I want to add an item in listbox when
if I `checked=true`, listbox add item 1, and
if `checked=false`, listbox add item 0

```
oda = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT IdGejala, Pertanyaan FROM tbGejala ", conn)
    ds = New DataSet
    Dim cbGejala As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
    cbGejala.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader
    cbGejala.TrueValue = 1        cbGejala.FalseValue = 0      cbGejala.ThreeState = 1         cbGejala.IndeterminateValue = System.DBNull.Value         cbGejala.DataPropertyName = "Checkbox"
    cbGejala.HeaderText = "Gejala anda"
    cbGejala.ReadOnly = False
    dgvDiagnosa.Columns.Add(cbGejala)
    ds.Clear()
    oda.Fill(ds, "tbGejala")
    dgvDiagnosa.DataSource = (ds.Tables("tbGejala"))
    Dim irow As Integer
    Dim nilai As String
    For irow = 0 To dgvDiagnosa.Rows.Count - 1
        If dgvDiagnosa.Rows(irow).Cells("Gejala anda").Value Then
            If cbGejala.TrueValue = 1 Then
                nilai = 1  checklistbox.add.item(nilai)
            End If           Else                nilai = 0 checklistbox.add.item(nilai)
        End If
    Next irow
```

> Additional information: Column named "Gejala anda" cannot be found.

Comment: Are you getting unexpected results or errors?  More info please :)

Comment: Additional information: Column named "Gejala anda" cannot be found.